# Redirect Output of python to file

Tags: bash, python, redirection

I have the following problem:

- I need to redirect standardoutput to output.file

I have a script that is written in python (I have no clue about python). I run the script using a bash terminal in linux (ubuntu) as follows:

```
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install pythonscript
pythonscript --argument > output.file
```

The result is,

- the pythonscript runs perfect,
- the output.file is empty,
- the output is visible in the bash terminal window which - to my knowledge - is the standardoutput.

Conclusion:

- Redirection in this case does not working.
- Unforunately I have no clue about python. I guess the problems comes due to the fact, that I am in some kind of an virtual environment `python3 -m venv venv`.

How can I redirect the output of that pythonscript to my output.file ?

Comment: Does the script write to `STDERR`? Try `pythonscrip --argument > stdout.file 2>stderr.file`